# Node.js crypto.publicEncrypt: 'Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line'

Tags: node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

I'm trying to use the public key encryption in crypto.js, I want to encrypt some message using `publicEncrypt`, and decrypt it with `privateDecrypt`.

```
const crypto=require('crypto');
let alice=crypto.getDiffieHellman('modp14');
alice.generateKeys();
let enc=crypto.publicEncrypt(alice.getPublicKey(),Buffer.from('hello'));
```

However, the `crypto.publicEncrypt` line is causing the following error:
"Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public key value returned by `crypto.DiffieHellman.getPublicKey()` is just the raw DH number, optionally encoded in base64 or hex. It is not in (any) PEM format or even ASN.1/DER format (which could easily be turned into PEM). Similarly `crypto.ECDH.getPublicKey()` is only the point (in conventional X9.62 format), not any PEM or DER format.

Moreover, DH and ECDH are not encryption algorithms, they are key-agreement (or secret-agreement) algorithms, and that operation is performed by `DiffieHellman.computeSecret()` or `ECDH.computeSecret()` respectively. Although not clearly documented, `publicEncrypt` actually calls OpenSSL's `EVP_PKEY_encrypt{_init,}` which doesn't support DH or ECDH, only RSA (with several choices of padding) and possibly GOST-wrap (I can't easily verify that and it may well be version dependent because upstream OpenSSL as of 1.1.0 a few years ago dropped the GOST algorithms).

In short, you can't do that.