# Node crypto instead of JSEncrypt for encryption with public key

Tags: node.js, encryption, node-crypto, jsencrypt

I have some public key which looks like `MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAO...` (392 chars).
It used in the browser to encrypt some strings with JSEncrypt.

How can I encrypt strings with that public key using NodeJS crypto module?

I tried this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt('MIIBIjA....', '111111')
console.log(encrypted.toString('base64'))
```

But got `error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`.

I also tried to convert the public key and the string into the buffer, got the same error.

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344351/node-js-crypto-publicencrypt-error-error0906d06cpem-routinespem-read-bion) help?

Comment: @RahulSingh, so should I just add `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` first line and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` last line and split string to lines with 64 chars length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the key in [`crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buffer)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key) is passed as a string, then it is interpreted as PEM encoded key by default.
A PEM encoded key consists of a header line, followed by the Base64 encoded body (i.e. the Base64 encoded data of the DER encoded key), and a footer line.
In the posted code snippet, the header line is missing (and presumably the footer line as well), which causes the error.

`crypto.publicEncrypt(key, buffer)` uses OAEP as padding by default. [JSEncrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/84) on the other hand only supports PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So if the implementation should be compatible to JSEncrypt, i.e. if the ciphertext should be decryptable with JSEncrypt, then PKCS#1 v1.5 padding must be specified explicitly.

The following NodeJS code encrypts a message with the crypto module and decrypts the ciphertext with JSEncrypt:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { JSEncrypt } = require('js-encrypt')

const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDNvs/qUMjkfq2E9o0qn03+KJE7
ASczEbn6q+kkthNBdmTsskikWsykpDPnLWhAVkmjz4alQyqw+mHYP9xhx8qUC4A3
tXY0ObxANUUKhUvR7zNj4vk4t8F2nP3erWvaG8J+sN3Ubr40ZYIYLS6UHYRFrqRD
CDhUtyjwERlz8KhLyQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

const privateKey = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`

// Encrypt with crypto module (RSA - PKCS#1 v1.5 Padding)
var ciphertext = crypto.publicEncrypt(
    {
        key: publicKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
    }, 
    Buffer.from('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog','utf8')
)
console.log(ciphertext.toString('base64'))

// Decrypt with JSEncrypt
var decrypt = new JSEncrypt()
decrypt.setPrivateKey(privateKey)
var decrypted = decrypt.decrypt(ciphertext.toString('base64'))
console.log(decrypted) // The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```